Need to fetch multiple clients using same interface based on a key
I have a below DI which will give me two different DatabaseClients.
_ = services.AddSingleton<IDbFactory>(x =>
{
    var dbFactory = new DbFactory(x.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>(), x.GetRequiredService<IKeyVaultManager>(), "**ClusterName1**");
    return dbFactory;
});

_ = services.AddSingleton<IDbFactory>(x =>
{
    var dbFactory = new DbFactory(x.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>(), x.GetRequiredService<IKeyVaultManager>(), "**ClusterName2**");
    return dbFactory;
});

Now I want to get specific client based on the basis of ClusterName as a key from the below constructor. Is there any way to achieve the same?
public class TestRepository : DbRepository<SomeEntity>, ITestRepository
{
    public TestRepository(ILogger<DbRepository<SomeEntity>> logger, **IDbFactory clientFactory**)
        : base(logger, clientFactory)
    {
    }
}


What are you using as the descriminator for deciding which implementation to inject?

In you're question it is not clear what should make the decision on what IDbFactory implementation should be used.
Are keyed services something you might can use?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0#keyed-services
For example:
_ = services.AddKeyedSingleton<IDbFactory>("TestCluster1", x =>
{
    var dbFactory = new DbFactory(x.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>(), x.GetRequiredService<IKeyVaultManager>(), "**TestCluster1**");
    return dbFactory;
});

_ = services.AddKeyedSingleton<IDbFactory>("TestCluster2", x =>
{
    var dbFactory = new DbFactory(x.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>(), x.GetRequiredService<IKeyVaultManager>(), "**TestCluster2**");
    return dbFactory;
});

In your constructor you can than use the following convention to access the correct service.
public class TestRepository : DbRepository<SomeEntity>, ITestRepository
{
    public TestRepository(ILogger<DbRepository<SomeEntity>> logger, [FromKeyedServices("TestCluster1")] IDbFactory clientFactory)
        : base(logger, clientFactory)
    {
    }
}


Avoid using answers to post questions back to the OP. Use comments for that. Additionally, link-only answers are frowned upon in SO since the links could change/go bad for whatever reason. They should be added as references along with the answer itself in the post.

I am using IServiceCollection in the DI and in that I am not able to get AddKeyedSingleton. And I want the client created out of the interface based on the ClusterName

@JuhiSaxena if you are not seeing the AddKeyedSingleton method it is probably because you are using an older version of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions NuGet packages. Try updating those and see if the method shows up. Keyed registration support was added fairly recently to the Microsoft container.

@julealgon/@Wouter Bunthof - I am able to connect with multiple cluster through my background service as per your suggestions. Thanks!
But I have another project which needs same implementation of AddKeyedSingleton, but while installing the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, version- 8.0.0.0, my Startup.cs is failing while configuring the services saying System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

@JuhiSaxena glad you got it working! As for your other issue, with just that error message it is hard to tell what could be happening. I suggest you open a separate question and provide a simple repro so folks can help you out with that.

@julealgon, raised one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78581303/need-to-implement-addkeyedsingleton-with-azure-function
