Need to implement AddKeyedSingleton with Azure Function
I have a below DI which will give me two different DatabaseClients in my Azure Function.
public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{    
    _ = services.AddKeyedSingleton<IDbFactory>("TestCluster1", x =>
    {
        var dbFactory = new DbFactory(x.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>(), x.GetRequiredService<IKeyVaultManager>(), "**TestCluster1**");
        return dbFactory;
    });

    _ = services.AddKeyedSingleton<IDbFactory>("TestCluster2", x =>
    {
        var dbFactory = new DbFactory(x.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>(), x.GetRequiredService<IKeyVaultManager>(), "**TestCluster2**");
        return dbFactory;
    });
}

My Startup.cs looks like
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(StartUp))]

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class StartUp : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            ConfigureServices(builder.Services);
        }

        private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Configurations
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddConfiguration(services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>())
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            services.AddInfrastructure(services, configuration);
        }
    }
}

The .csproj for FunctionApp looks like
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <DockerFastModeProjectMountDirectory>/home/site/wwwroot</DockerFastModeProjectMountDirectory>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.11.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.17.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Since AddKeyedSingleton requires Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, and I have installed it, but in my Startup.cs, I get this error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I have verified that its transitive package being loaded as 8.0.0.0 version only. Can someone please help me out fixing this error?

Is the reference in your csproj file? You should probably add that to the question.

Imo -> go for a .Net 8 version because its LTS and this one will be EOL in 2025.
Then you are in the concept of isolated workers, there is another approach of the external startup class.
ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows

I tried upgrading .Net version to 8.0, but same issue

I believe you, did you changed your startup way? like its now program.cs and work with args.

This is definitely the way to go @JuhiSaxena . Any time you spend on the old in-process functions model and .NET6 is just going to be wasted time really. If you can spend a little bit of time on this, switch to the out-of-process (so-called isolated) functions and .NET8. You can create a brand new project from the templates to see how that new project structure looks like to help in your migration.

Thanks @Elty/ @julealgon, I have migrated my project to Isolated worker model and it worked.

Great to hear that @JuhiSaxena ;)
